# c++ Struct Output Using Class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, struct, cout

I once new a bit of c++, and am trying to relearn.  I am currently working on a project which will eventually store, sort, and display rainfall per month.  Right now I am trying to print out array of months (structs), but it isn't working.  How can I get this to correctly print out each months info(month, rain)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class rainfall
{
public:
struct Month
{
    string month;
    double rain;
};

//private:
void Rainfall()
{
    Month months[12] = { { "January", 0 }, { "February", 0 }, { "March", 0 }, { "April", 0 }, { "May", 0 }, { "June", 0 }, { "July", 0 }, { "August", 0 }, { "September", 0 }, { "October", 0 }, { "Novermber", 0 }, { "December", 0 }};
}
};

int main()
{
rainfall newMonths;
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << newMonths[i].month  << "   " <<  newMonths[i].rain << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it isn't working" mean? I mean, aside from declaring/defining your `rainfall` constructor wrong (typo in capitalisation, return type whatttt) and declaring only a _local_ variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RainFall
```

Class names should start with an uppercase character, and if you are using the camel case convention, every first letter of the class name should be upper case as well.

```
struct Month
{
  string month;
  double rain;
};

vector<Month> months;
```

You need a variable to store the months.

```
RainFall() : months{ { "January", 0 }, { "February", 0 }, { "March", 0 }, { "April", 0 }, { "May", 0 }, { "June", 0 }, { "July", 0 }, { "August", 0 }, { "September", 0 }, { "October", 0 }, { "Novermber", 0 }, { "December", 0 } }
{
}
```

The constructor of a class has to have the same name as the class and for initializing class attributes, you should use the initializer section.

```
cout << newMonths.months[i].month << " " << newMonths.months[i].rain << endl;
```

You are accessing the month attribute, so don't forget it.

Here is the full code: https://gist.github.com/HappyCerberus/d9e5a8e0ad18c5e393b8

Comment: Thank you Let_Me_Be, I looked at your code, realized I needed to create my array outside my constructor.  Then I used your cout statement and all worked good.